# how to know if file transferred successfully from local to hdfs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hadoop, hdfs

we want to copy local files to HDFS

example

```
su  hdfs -c 'hadoop fs -put -f /tmp/hadoop-streaming.jar /hdp/apps/2.6.4.0-91/mapreduce'
```

this command actually , switch user to HDFS and copy the local file under `/tmp` to  `/hdp/apps/2.6.4.0-91/mapreduce`

the big question is - how to know if file transferred successfully ?

is it ok just to capture the $? from CLI ?

as

```
su  hdfs -c 'hadoop fs -put -f /tmp/hadoop-streaming.jar /hdp/apps/2.6.4.0-91/mapreduce'
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && echo "congratulations - files transferred successfully - well done !!!!!!!!!!!!!! "
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the approach to test if file copied to HDFS should be by $?

as

```
[[ $? -eq 0 ]]
```

standard error will captured and results from $? reflects the real status